# Signature: Place signature graphic right above a rule line

Tags: formatting, includegraphics

I got the following code the last page of a contract:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
%here I can put a date
\rule{3cm}{0.5pt}
Date
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}
%here I can put a signature
\rule{9cm}{0.5pt}
  
Signature
\end{minipage}
```

The output is:

[image]

Now when actually trying to fill it with content like this:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
01.01.2022
\rule{3cm}{0.5pt}
Date
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{img/signature}
\rule{9cm}{0.5pt}
  
Signature
\end{minipage}
```

the result is not as expected:

[image]

Comment: Unless you add a \nefwline, \\ or \par, if they **can** fit in the same line, they **will** go in the same line.  Personally, I would have used a tabular instead of a minipage.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest `tabular*`. Adjust the widths to your page setup. For the date I used `\today`, but any explicit date can be set at the same place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{%
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  w{l}{3cm}
  c
  w{l}{6cm}
  @{}
}
\today && \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=1.5cm]{example-image} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
Date && Signature
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Peraphs is missing an example of the date as in the MWE of the user.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for the note, I added the date.

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnKormylo mentioned:

Adding a new line behind the signature graphic did the job.

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
01.01.2022
\rule{3cm}{0.5pt}
Date
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{img/signature} \newline
\rule{9cm}{0.5pt}
  
Signature
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Could you write up a proper answer that highlights (in code) exactly what needs to be done, rather than referencing some other element (comment) on this site?